# URL encoding issue with cron and wget

Tags: bash, cron, wget

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q 'http://requestb.in/1fq0r3s1?foo=a%2Bb' -O /dev/null
```

If I run this from the commandline and then inspect at 
http://requestb.in/1fq0r3s1?inspect I see

> Query String
>   **foo**: a+b

Which is what I would expect.

However when the bash script is run by CRON, I see

> Query String
>   **foo**: a b

It looks like something has decoded the URL before sending, converting the `%2B` into `+` which is then interpreted as a space by the receiving server.

**Can anyone explain this and help me figure out how to get the script to behave in cron as it does when run from the command line?**

(Note: `curl` does not suffer this same behaviour, but I'm interested in learning why `wget` behaves this way)

Answer (score 0):

> %(percent) means a new line in cron!

So you either have to escape it like this `foo=a\%2Bb` or
put your command in a bash file and run that file in crontab.

Comment: I know % is special in cron entries but this is in an external bash script; there is no % in the crontab. And if I change it to curl then the problem is gone.